# How can i build a for function for matrix?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

Now i have a list like below:

```
mylist
[[1]]
[1] 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
...
```

I would like to make every list into a 3*3 matrix by a for loop function like:

```
for (i in 1:N){
m[i]=matrix(mylist[[i]],nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)

}
```

But it doesn't work out?

What else i can do ?

Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stackoverflow. From the R tag-wiki, *R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, and graphics. Please supplement your question with a minimal reproducible example. For statistical questions please use http://stats.stackexchange.com.* Also, do be sure to [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and at least brows through [the SO help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: You should also read the error messages more carefully and post the complete error message rather than writing "doesn't work".. When you try to assign with an index on the LHS and the object being indexed doesn't exist, you get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop for that. You can use `lapply`:

```
## First, make up some sample data
set.seed(1)
mylist <- replicate(2, sample(0:1, 9, TRUE), FALSE)

## Let's work on a copy in case you need the original
m <- mylist 
m
# [[1]]
# [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1

## Here's the actual transformation
m[] <- lapply(m, matrix, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
m
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    1
# [2,]    1    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    1
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    1
# [3,]    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m=list()
for (i in 1:length(mylist) ){
m[[i]] = matrix( mylist[[i]], nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
}

> m
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    0    1    1
```